# Adding unintendedly hyphen end of the path - IMacros and Batch Clip Command

Tags: batch-file, command-line, automation, imacros

I have a one batch script which takes the full path of one zip file.

1. Copy to clipboard this path
2. Start a firefox and Imacro
3. Start to fill in a form
4. Last part in the form, click the browse button and copy the full path of zip file for uploading this file to the system

**Here is the batch script :**

```
set wp=D:\workset\MC_DIM_DXI_CFG_DEV\_exchange\
   // some coding in here
    d:
cd %wp%

    for %%i in (x_to_y*.zip) do (
      echo %wp%%%i| clip
    )

    @echo please wait, a new firefox browser will open with macro in 6 seconds
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 6000 > nul
        start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  imacros://run/?m=xToy.iim
```

Here is the Imacros script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8530828 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://example.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:Login ATTR=NAME:USER CONTENT=username
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:Login ATTR=NAME:PASSWORD CONTENT=password
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:Login ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Mein<SP>Arbeitsplatz
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:GIS
FRAME NAME="main"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Problemmanagement<SP>-<SP>TXT:Example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:EI<SP>-<SP>Problemmanagement
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Import
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:import
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://dms.bmw.com/gis/icons/add_dokument.gif
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:frm_edit_container_doku ATTR=NAME:p_Dok_Name CONTENT=example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:frm_edit_container_doku ATTR=NAME:p_Dok_Searchword CONTENT=example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:frm_edit_container_doku ATTR=NAME:p_Dok_Shortcut CONTENT=example
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=NAME:frm_edit_container_doku ATTR=NAME:FILE CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}
```

At the last line of the Imacros Script, I click the browse button for upload a zip file. I copy the full path which is already in my clipboard. **The problem is, at the end of my path the hyphen character automatically adding so the system cannot take the correct zip file.**

Why and Where this hyphen comes ? How can i get rid of this problem ?

I am stuck in this problem like 1 week. Any help, idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a \ in there like this:

```
echo %wp%\%%i| clip
```

You should also start with this to verify that you are putting what you think you are on the clipboard

```
echo %wp%\%%i
```